# How to open a desktop entry as root?

Tags: bash, user-interface, root, ubuntu-18.04

I have a desktop entry placed in `usr/share/applications` that runs a Java jar and looks something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=pkexec /usr/bin/java -jar something-something.jar
Icon=default.png
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=foo
GenericName=bar
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Game
```

I need to run the JAR as `root`, so I tried using `pkexec` to have a GUI password prompt appear so I can run the JAR as `sudo` (I am using Ubuntu 18). However, it would not work and when I tried to open the desktop entry in the terminal (using something like `xdg-open`) I got: `Refusing to render service to dead parents`

I believe the problem is with my using `pkexec`. While I would be interested to know why `pkexec` does not work for my usage, I would like to know what I can do to run the JAR with `sudo` from the GUI? That way, when I click on the desktop entry from the menu, a password prompt appears.

**Edit:**

Actually, I've been using `gtk-open` and getting the dead parents error. `xdg-open` results in the desktop entry simply being opened in `vim`.

Answer (score 4):

`pkexec` is part of PolicyKit, which allows a finer distribution of rights. To execute programs with graphical user interface using pkexec, you can use the following call:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /usr/bin/java -jar something-something.jar
```